# Sending files from a client to a server and then reading the file in another client using sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, sendfile

There are two clients and a server in the application. The two clients communicate with each other via the server. When one client sends a message to the server, the server stores the message as a text file in the server, where file name is clientid_timestamp.txt. The server then sends the file to the other client that reads the file and displays its content on its terminal.

I have written the code for the client and the server given below.The issue that I am facing is that the client is not able to get the file from the server print it's contents.It doesn't show an output in the terminal.

[Server side image in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1sHX.png)

[client side image in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ehUy.png)

Server code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 3
#define BUFFER_SZ 2048
#define SIZE 1024

static _Atomic unsigned int cli_count = 0;
static int uid = 10;

/* Client structure */
typedef struct{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sockfd;
    int uid;
    char name[32];
} client_t;

client_t *clients[MAX_CLIENTS];

pthread_mutex_t clients_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void str_overwrite_stdout() {
    printf("\r%s", "> ");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void print_client_addr(struct sockaddr_in addr){
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d",
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff00) >> 8,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff0000) >> 16,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff000000) >> 24);
}

/* Add clients to queue */
void queue_add(client_t *cl){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(!clients[i]){
            clients[i] = cl;
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Remove clients to queue */
void queue_remove(int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid == uid){
                clients[i] = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}


void send_file(int sockfd){
    int n;
    char data[SIZE] = {0};

    FILE *fp = fopen("clientid_timestamp.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    
    }

    while(fgets(data, SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        if (send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0) == -1) {
        perror("[-]Error in sending file.");
        exit(1);
        }
        printf("hello");
        bzero(data, SIZE);
    }

}

/* Send message to all clients except sender */
void send_message(char *s, int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid != uid){
                printf("MESSAGE SENT TO %s:%d \n",inet_ntoa(clients[i]->address.sin_addr),ntohs(clients[i]->address.sin_port));
                send_file(clients[i]->uid);
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Handle all communication with the client */
void *handle_client(void *arg){

    char buff_out[BUFFER_SZ];
    char name[32];
    int leave_flag = 0;

    cli_count++;
    client_t *cli = (client_t *)arg;

    
    
    // Name

    bzero(buff_out, BUFFER_SZ);

    while(1){
        if (leave_flag) {
            break;
        }

        int receive = recv(cli->sockfd, buff_out, BUFFER_SZ, 0);
        if (receive > 0){
            if(strlen(buff_out) > 0){

                FILE *f = fopen("clientid_timestamp.txt", "w");
                if (f == NULL){
                    printf("Error opening file!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }

                /* print some text */
                fprintf(f, "%s", buff_out);
                send_message(buff_out, cli->uid);
                fclose(f);
                printf("\n");
            } 
        } 
        else {
            printf("ERROR: -1\n");
            leave_flag = 1;
        }

        bzero(buff_out, BUFFER_SZ);
    }

  /* Delete client from queue and yield thread */
    close(cli->sockfd);
    queue_remove(cli->uid);
    free(cli);
    cli_count--;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int option = 1;
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
  pthread_t tid;

  /* Socket settings */
  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  /* Ignore pipe signals */
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    if(setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET,(SO_REUSEPORT | SO_REUSEADDR),(char*)&option,sizeof(option)) < 0){
        perror("ERROR: setsockopt failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Bind */
  if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: Socket binding failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  /* Listen */
  if (listen(listenfd, 10) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: Socket listening failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    char exit[] = "exit_client";
    char accepted[] = "accept_client";

    while(1){
        socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);

        /* Check if max clients is reached */
        if((cli_count) == MAX_CLIENTS){
            printf("Max clients reached. Rejected: ");
            print_client_addr(cli_addr);
            printf(":%d\n", cli_addr.sin_port);
            send(connfd, exit, strlen(exit), 0);
            close(connfd);
            continue;
        }
        else{
            
            send(connfd, accepted, strlen(accepted), 0);
            client_t *cli = (client_t *)malloc(sizeof(client_t));
            cli->address = cli_addr;
            cli->sockfd = connfd;
            cli->uid = uid++;

            printf("Client Connected : ");
            printf("%s:%d \n",inet_ntoa(cli->address.sin_addr),ntohs(cli->address.sin_port));
            
            /* Add client to the queue and fork thread */
            queue_add(cli);
            pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &handle_client, (void*)cli);

            /* Reduce CPU usage */
            sleep(1);
        }

        /* Client settings */
        
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Client Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define LENGTH 2048
#define MAX 10000 
// Global variables
volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;
int sockfd = 0;
char name[32];

void str_overwrite_stdout() {
  printf("%s", "> ");
  fflush(stdout);
}

void str_trim_lf (char* arr, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { // trim \n
    if (arr[i] == '\n') {
      arr[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}

void catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(int sig) {
    flag = 1;
}

void send_msg_handler() {
  char message[LENGTH] = {};
    char buffer[LENGTH + 32] = {};

  while(1) {
    str_overwrite_stdout();
    fgets(message, LENGTH, stdin);
    //str_trim_lf(message, LENGTH);

    if (strcmp(message, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
    } else {
      sprintf(buffer, "%s\n", message);
      send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    }

        bzero(message, LENGTH);
    bzero(buffer, LENGTH + 32);
  }
  catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(2);
}

void recv_msg_handler() {
    

    while (1) {

      int n;
      FILE *fp;
      char buff[1024]="",*ptr=buff;
      int bytes=0,bytes_received;
      while(bytes_received = recv(sockfd,ptr, 1, 0)){

        printf("%s\n",ptr);
        if(bytes_received==-1){
          perror("recieve");
          exit(3);
        }

        if(*ptr=='\n' ) break;
          ptr++; //each times we increment it it points to the buffer element
      }

      *ptr=0;
      ptr=buff;
      printf("%s\n",ptr);
      str_overwrite_stdout();
    }         
}



int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);

    signal(SIGINT, catch_ctrl_c_and_exit);



    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    /* Socket settings */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);


  // Connect to Server
  int err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  if (err == -1) {
        printf("ERROR: connect\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  char exit_client[] = "exit_client";
  char buff[MAX];
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
  recv(sockfd, buff, 1024, 0);
  if((strcmp(buff, exit_client) == 0)){
    printf("limit exceeded , closing the client \n");
        close(sockfd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

  else{
    printf("client accepted by the server and limit not exceeded \n");
    }
  
    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    pthread_t send_msg_thread;
  if(pthread_create(&send_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) send_msg_handler, NULL) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: pthread\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pthread_t recv_msg_thread;
  if(pthread_create(&recv_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) recv_msg_handler, NULL) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: pthread\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1){
        if(flag){
            printf("\nBye\n");
            break;
    }
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT-1**

I have made the changes suggested by the user stackinside and the code now works , but I have being facing a new issue for the past few hours and I am not able to wrap my head around it as what could the reason for it.

The issue that arises now is that the client is only able to send the message once to other client and vice versa and then it is not able to send any more messages except a new line.The updated code based on the changes I made

[client side image in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ1If.png)

[server side image in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNoeE.png)

Server code :

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 3
#define BUFFER_SZ 2048
#define SIZE 1024

static _Atomic unsigned int cli_count = 0;
static int uid = 10;

/* Client structure */
typedef struct{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sockfd;
    int uid;
    char name[32];
} client_t;

client_t *clients[MAX_CLIENTS];

void str_trim_lf (char* arr, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { // trim \n
    if (arr[i] == '\n') {
      arr[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}

pthread_mutex_t clients_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void str_overwrite_stdout() {
    printf("\r%s", "> ");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void print_client_addr(struct sockaddr_in addr){
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d",
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff00) >> 8,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff0000) >> 16,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff000000) >> 24);
}

/* Add clients to queue */
void queue_add(client_t *cl){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(!clients[i]){
            clients[i] = cl;
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Remove clients to queue */
void queue_remove(int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid == uid){
                clients[i] = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}


void send_file(int sockfd){
    int n;
    char data[SIZE] = {0};

    FILE *fp = fopen("clientid_timestamp.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    
    }

    while(fgets(data, SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        if (send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0) == -1) {
        perror("[-]Error in sending file.");
        exit(1);
        }
        bzero(data, SIZE);
    }
}

/* Send message to all clients except sender */
void send_message(char *s, int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid != uid){
                printf("MESSAGE SENT TO %s:%d \n",inet_ntoa(clients[i]->address.sin_addr),ntohs(clients[i]->address.sin_port));
                send_file(clients[i]->sockfd);
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Handle all communication with the client */
void *handle_client(void *arg){

    char buff_out[BUFFER_SZ];
    char name[32];
    int leave_flag = 0;

    cli_count++;
    client_t *cli = (client_t *)arg;

    
    
    // Name

    bzero(buff_out, BUFFER_SZ);

    while(1){
        if (leave_flag) {
            break;
        }

        int receive = recv(cli->sockfd, buff_out, BUFFER_SZ, 0);
        if (receive > 0){
            if(strlen(buff_out) > 0){

                FILE *f = fopen("clientid_timestamp.txt", "w");
                if (f == NULL){
                    printf("Error opening file!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }

                /* print some text */
                fprintf(f, "%s", buff_out);
                fclose(f);
                send_message(buff_out, cli->uid);
                printf("\n");
            } 
        } 
        else {
            printf("ERROR: -1\n");
            leave_flag = 1;
        }

        bzero(buff_out, BUFFER_SZ);
    }

  /* Delete client from queue and yield thread */
    close(cli->sockfd);
    queue_remove(cli->uid);
    free(cli);
    cli_count--;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int option = 1;
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
  pthread_t tid;

  /* Socket settings */
  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  /* Ignore pipe signals */
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    if(setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET,(SO_REUSEPORT | SO_REUSEADDR),(char*)&option,sizeof(option)) < 0){
        perror("ERROR: setsockopt failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Bind */
  if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: Socket binding failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  /* Listen */
  if (listen(listenfd, 10) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: Socket listening failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    char exit[] = "exit_client";
    char accepted[] = "accept_client";

    while(1){
        socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);

        /* Check if max clients is reached */
        if((cli_count) == MAX_CLIENTS){
            printf("Max clients reached. Rejected: ");
            print_client_addr(cli_addr);
            printf(":%d\n", cli_addr.sin_port);
            send(connfd, exit, strlen(exit), 0);
            close(connfd);
            continue;
        }
        else{
            
            send(connfd, accepted, strlen(accepted), 0);
            client_t *cli = (client_t *)malloc(sizeof(client_t));
            cli->address = cli_addr;
            cli->sockfd = connfd;
            cli->uid = uid++;

            printf("Client Connected : ");
            printf("%s:%d \n",inet_ntoa(cli->address.sin_addr),ntohs(cli->address.sin_port));
            
            /* Add client to the queue and fork thread */
            queue_add(cli);
            pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &handle_client, (void*)cli);

            /* Reduce CPU usage */
            sleep(1);
        }

        /* Client settings */
        
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define LENGTH 2048
#define MAX 10000 
// Global variables
volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;
int sockfd = 0;
char name[32];

void str_overwrite_stdout() {
  printf("%s", "> ");
  fflush(stdout);
}

void str_trim_lf (char* arr, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { // trim \n
    if (arr[i] == '\n') {
      arr[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}

void catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(int sig) {
    flag = 1;
}

void send_msg_handler() {
  char message[LENGTH] = {};
    char buffer[LENGTH + 32] = {};

  while(1) {
    str_overwrite_stdout();
    fgets(message, LENGTH, stdin);
    str_trim_lf(message, LENGTH);

    if (strcmp(message, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
    } else {
      sprintf(buffer, "%s\n", message);
      send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    }

        bzero(message, LENGTH);
    bzero(buffer, LENGTH + 32);
  }
  catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(2);
}

void recv_msg_handler() {

    int n;
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[1024]="",*ptr=buff;
    int bytes=0,bytes_received;
  
    while (1) {

      
      while(bytes_received = recv(sockfd,ptr, 1, 0)){

        if(bytes_received==-1){
          perror("recieve");
          exit(3);
        }

        if(*ptr=='\n' ) break;
          ptr++; //each times we increment it it points to the buffer element
      }
      *ptr=0;
      str_trim_lf(buff, strlen(buff));
      ptr=buff;
      printf("%s \n",ptr);
      str_overwrite_stdout();
    }         
}



int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);

    signal(SIGINT, catch_ctrl_c_and_exit);



    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    /* Socket settings */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);


  // Connect to Server
  int err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  if (err == -1) {
        printf("ERROR: connect\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  char exit_client[] = "exit_client";
  char buff[MAX];
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
  recv(sockfd, buff, 1024, 0);
  if((strcmp(buff, exit_client) == 0)){
    printf("limit exceeded , closing the client \n");
        close(sockfd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

  else{
    printf("client accepted by the server and limit not exceeded \n");
    }
  
    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    pthread_t send_msg_thread;
  if(pthread_create(&send_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) send_msg_handler, NULL) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: pthread\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pthread_t recv_msg_thread;
  if(pthread_create(&recv_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) recv_msg_handler, NULL) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: pthread\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1){
        if(flag){
            printf("\nBye\n");
            break;
    }
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT-2**

So now I changed the fgets to freads and removed all the unnecessary bzero and changed the strlen to sizeof as suggested by the comments of user207421 , Martin James and stackinside .It finally works , I agree there is still a lot of room for optimisation , but it works for now and thanks for the effort.

[client side image in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Uay.png)

[Server side image in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtEMs.png)

**Client side code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define LENGTH 2048
#define MAX 10000 
#define CHUNK_SIZE 512
// Global variables
volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;
int sockfd = 0;
char name[32];

void str_overwrite_stdout() {
  printf("%s", "> ");
  fflush(stdout);
}

void str_trim_lf (char* arr, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { // trim \n
    if (arr[i] == '\n') {
      arr[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}

void catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(int sig) {
    flag = 1;
}

void send_msg_handler() {
  char message[LENGTH] = {};
    char buffer[LENGTH + 32] = {};

  while(1) {
    str_overwrite_stdout();
    
    fgets(message, LENGTH, stdin);
    str_trim_lf(message, LENGTH);

    if (strcmp(message, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
    } 
    
    else {
      sprintf(buffer, "%s\n", message);
      send(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    }

        bzero(message, LENGTH);
    bzero(buffer, LENGTH + 32);
  }

  catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(2);
}

void recv_msg_handler() {

    while (1) {

        int n;
        FILE *fp;
        char buff[1024],*ptr=buff;
        int bytes=0,bytes_received;
        int file_size;

        recv(sockfd, buff, CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
        file_size = atoi(buff);
        
        str_trim_lf(buff, sizeof(buff));

        printf("%s \n",buff);
        str_overwrite_stdout();
    }         
}



int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);

    signal(SIGINT, catch_ctrl_c_and_exit);



    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    /* Socket settings */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);


  // Connect to Server
  int err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  if (err == -1) {
        printf("ERROR: connect\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  char exit_client[] = "exit_client";
  char buff[MAX];
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
  recv(sockfd, buff, 1024, 0);

  if((strcmp(buff, exit_client) == 0)){
    printf("limit exceeded , closing the client \n");
        close(sockfd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

  else{
    printf("client accepted by the server and limit not exceeded \n");
    }
  
    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    pthread_t send_msg_thread;
  if(pthread_create(&send_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) send_msg_handler, NULL) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: pthread\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pthread_t recv_msg_thread;
  if(pthread_create(&recv_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) recv_msg_handler, NULL) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: pthread\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1){
        if(flag){
            printf("\nBye\n");
            break;
    }
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Server side:**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 3
#define BUFFER_SZ 2048
#define SIZE 1024
#define CHUNK_SIZE 512

static _Atomic unsigned int cli_count = 0;
static int uid = 10;

/* Client structure */
typedef struct{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sockfd;
    int uid;
    char name[32];
} client_t;

client_t *clients[MAX_CLIENTS];

void str_trim_lf (char* arr, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { // trim \n
    if (arr[i] == '\n') {
      arr[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}

pthread_mutex_t clients_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void str_overwrite_stdout() {
    printf("\r%s", "> ");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void print_client_addr(struct sockaddr_in addr){
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d",
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff00) >> 8,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff0000) >> 16,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff000000) >> 24);
}

/* Add clients to queue */
void queue_add(client_t *cl){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(!clients[i]){
            clients[i] = cl;
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Remove clients to queue */
void queue_remove(int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid == uid){
                clients[i] = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}


void send_file(int sockfd){
    int n;
    char data[SIZE] = {0};

    FILE *fp = fopen("clientid_timestamp.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    
    }

    char file_data[CHUNK_SIZE];
    size_t nbytes = 0;

    while ( (nbytes = fread(data, sizeof(char), CHUNK_SIZE,fp)) > 0){
        
        if (send(sockfd, data, nbytes, 0) == -1) {
        perror("[-]Error in sending file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    }
}

/* Send message to all clients except sender */
void send_message(char *s, int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid != uid){
                printf("MESSAGE SENT TO %s:%d \n",inet_ntoa(clients[i]->address.sin_addr),ntohs(clients[i]->address.sin_port));
                send_file(clients[i]->sockfd);
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Handle all communication with the client */
void *handle_client(void *arg){

    char buff_out[BUFFER_SZ];
    char name[32];
    int leave_flag = 0;

    cli_count++;
    client_t *cli = (client_t *)arg;

    // Name

    bzero(buff_out, BUFFER_SZ);

    while(1){
        if (leave_flag) {
            break;
        }

        int receive = recv(cli->sockfd, buff_out, BUFFER_SZ, 0);
        if (receive > 0){
            if(strlen(buff_out) > 0){

                FILE *f = fopen("clientid_timestamp.txt", "w");
                if (f == NULL){
                    printf("Error opening file!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }

                /* print some text */
                fprintf(f, "%s", buff_out);
                fclose(f);
                send_message(buff_out, cli->uid);
                printf("\n");
            } 
        } 

        else {
            printf("ERROR: -1\n");
            leave_flag = 1;
        }

    }

  /* Delete client from queue and yield thread */
    close(cli->sockfd);
    queue_remove(cli->uid);
    free(cli);
    cli_count--;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int option = 1;
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    pthread_t tid;

  /* Socket settings */
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  /* Ignore pipe signals */
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    if(setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET,(SO_REUSEPORT | SO_REUSEADDR),(char*)&option,sizeof(option)) < 0){
        perror("ERROR: setsockopt failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Bind */
    if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR: Socket binding failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  /* Listen */
    if (listen(listenfd, 10) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR: Socket listening failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    char exit[] = "exit_client";
    char accepted[] = "accept_client";

    while(1){
        socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);

        /* Check if max clients is reached */
        if((cli_count) == MAX_CLIENTS){
            printf("Max clients reached. Rejected: ");
            print_client_addr(cli_addr);
            printf(":%d\n", cli_addr.sin_port);
            send(connfd, exit, sizeof(exit), 0);
            close(connfd);
            continue;
        }
        else{
            
            send(connfd, accepted, sizeof(accepted), 0);
            client_t *cli = (client_t *)malloc(sizeof(client_t));
            cli->address = cli_addr;
            cli->sockfd = connfd;
            cli->uid = uid++;

            printf("Client Connected : ");
            printf("%s:%d \n",inet_ntoa(cli->address.sin_addr),ntohs(cli->address.sin_port));
            
            /* Add client to the queue and fork thread */
            queue_add(cli);
            pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &handle_client, (void*)cli);

            /* Reduce CPU usage */
            sleep(1);
        }

        /* Client settings */
        
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. How is your troubleshooting going? Have you narrowed down the problem? What are you stuck on?

Comment: `send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0` ignores the actual count of data just read, so you are sending junk. You should use `fread()`, not `fgets()`, to get that count. The `bzero()` calls are unnecessary throughout. You aren't telling the clients how long the file is, nor are you closing the socket after sending the file, so the clients have no idea when to stop reading. Receiving one byte at a time is extremely inefficient. I don't see why you have to process newlines at the client. You aren't sending to the clients' `sockfd`. You are printing something in the client even if there was an error.

Comment: The new issue is for the same reasons I already stated and which you have done very little about.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am currently facing an issue with the client not able to receive messages properly , currently troubleshooting based on the feedback received by the user stackinside

Comment: @user207421 will work on that , I was focused on the client side for the past few hours , thanks

Comment: It's got bzero and strlen in it, so it's almost certainly broken:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side:

- `send_file(clients[i]->uid);` ought to be `send_file(clients[i]->sockfd);`
- `fclose(f);` should probably go *before* `send_message(buff_out, cli->uid);`

Client side:

- `printf("%s\n",ptr);` (before `if(bytes_received==-1)`) ought to be removed

There are other inconsistencies, unused variables, etc. This reivew is very limited.